# How do i create a template function definition with a template class as input

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, generics

Say I have the following classes:

```cpp
/* Frame.hpp */
template<class PayloadType>
class Frame {
    int address;
    PayloadType payload;
}
/* RequestPacket.hpp */
template<class PayloadType>
class RequestPacket { // Also a similar ResponsePacket exists
    Command command; // Command is an enum
    PayloadType payload;
}

/* GetMeanTemperatureRequest.hpp */
class GetMeanTemperatureRequest { // Many different Requests and Responses
    Period period; // Again, Period is an enum
}
```

And I have the following function:

```cpp
/* Serializer.hpp */
template<class From, To>
size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const From& input, To buffer);
```

Then I would like to instantiate this function for, lets say Frame:

```cpp
/* Frame.cpp */
#include "Serializer.hpp"
template<class PayloadType> // These 2 lines are the
template<>                  // subject of my question
size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const Frame<PayloadType>& input, uint8_t* buffer) {
  // implementation
}
```

Then I will get `error: too many template-parameter-lists`.

If I remove template<> then I'll get `error: prototype for std::size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const Frame<PayloadType>&, uint8_t*) does not match any in class Serializer`

If I change the two `template<...>`s around it doesn't help either

What does the compiler want?

Comment: You cannot **partial** specialize functions/methods.

Comment: What you want is a partial specialization of a function template. That is not supported. But you could overload the function symbol name with another function template for `Frame`.

Comment: @Quimby Do you mean I create an overload with the signature
template<class PayloadType, To>
size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const Frame<PayloadType>& input, To buffer);

Comment: *"`/* Frame.cpp */`"*. Implementation of template doesn't go in cpp files, they should stay visible where they are used, so header is the right place.

Comment: rather than text to describe code why not post the code? Its not really that hard: `// Command is an enum` -> `enum Command { a,b};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A specialization needs to match the primary declaration.  In your primary declaration you have:

```
template<class From, To>
size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const From& input, To buffer);
```

so your specialization needs to be in the form of

```
template<>
size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const concrete_from_type& input, concrete_to_type buffer);
```

What you are doing is trying combine a specialization with another template to try and get a partial specialization but that is not allowed.  What you can do instead is just add another overload of your function like

```
template<class PayloadType, To>
size_t Serializer::serializeTo(const Frame<PayloadType>& input, To buffer);
```

Comment: Alright, and does this have to be in the class declaration? Because Frame declares Serializer as a friend class and thus #includes  Serializer.hpp, but if I have to declare `serializeTo(const Frame<PayloadType>& input, To buffer);` in Serializer.hpp then I have to #include Frame.hpp there. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Typhaon Yes, that would cause a circular inclusion issue.  You might be able to solve that using forward declarations but I would have to see the actual code to know.  Another option is to not make a `Serialize` class and just have `serializeTo` as a free function.  You could also have a `Serialize` namespace and have `serializeTo` as a function in that namespace.  That lets you get out of have in include anything as the `serializeTo`'s in the different `Serialize` namespaces will all get combined when compiling.

Comment: Forward declaration did the trick! Thank you